# IOS - Phonegap - barcodescanner

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to make an app which uses the barcodescanner plugin for IOS which comes with the phonegap plugin library (latest build / phonegap 1.4). I have allready made the Android version with the same plugin for android, and it worked fine. I have followed the instructions step by step and it won't work for me.

I'm getting an com.phonegap.barcodeScanner not found, and i have checked that the plist is correct etc.

I have copied the new scanneroverlay.xib to the project so i don't have to play with the overlay.

I have copied all the mm c h files to the plugin folder. No error when building. Does i have to compile the plugin or??? is there someone who has a test app or a good idea please.

Getting a little frustrated.

Kind regards.
/Mikael

Comment: were you coding your IOS application [phonegap] in Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a reference to the barcodescanner.js in the index.html file, and that it is finding it okay.